# How to use new HTML5 tags when they aren't fully implemented?

Tags: html

I've done a little bit of playing around with the new HTML5 tags and read up on all the new ones at W3cschools, etc. and I'm a little confused.

If I create an HTML page that uses "areas", "sections", "asides", etc. Nothing happens?  I have to manually style them - which is FINE, but am I missing something? What's the point of declaring a tag an "aside" if I have to make it ASIDE (common css: float:right;width:30%, sorta thing)?
Why not just stay with DIV tags and style them?

I also noticed new attributes, such as "draggable", but, surprise-surprise, it doesn't drag!  I have to code it to drag too (javascript/jquery??) ?  What's the point of declaring it draggable?  I can create a div tag and drag it using JQuery, so someone please enlighten me as to what's so "whoopty doo" about html5?

Comment: Show your code, or it didn't happen.

Comment: there's no code to show.  this question is at a basic level, where i'm trying to determine what advantages there are to using the new html5 tags, such as aside, article, section, etc.  Browsers that don't support html5 will probably look at the tags and render them as div tags anyway, so, i ask again, what's the point?

Comment: ....as well as what's the point of doing something like 
<table draggable="true" (or whatever the syntax is), if it doesn't actually drag - i have to add javascript to actually make it drag.

Comment: Those are called semantic tags. They don't "do" anything. The page will just be easier to parse by machines, like screen readers and search engines, because the tags actually describe the content. There are other aspects of HTML5 that "do" things, like canvas, video, audio, forms, offline, etc.

Comment: I can see where the confusion would set it. These tags are added for semantic markup only. Meaning, they're only there as "page markers". Just think of them as organizational/outlining elements that help search engines, screen readers and the like figure out what your page is saying/how it's structured - like a skeletal outline. They're not necessary, but do add a ton of semantic strength to your page. You can also just style these tags directly and use them as you would the DIV tag - which semantically says absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how the web changes in respect to HTML.

1. First new tags are created by browser makers for advanced users to try out.
2. Then they are added to the standard
3. Then they actually get implemented in the various browsers and devices.
4. Then they become widespread and useful.
5. Then they become universal and are implemented by 99.9% of devices.

For the tags mentioned they are probably between steps 2 and 3

It may not be "whoopty doo" but this is how changes occurs in this system

Developers who accept, embrace and use this pattern of evolution help move this process along.
It's a bit zen-like.

Additionally, as Aaron points out in his comment above (+1), these particular tags are semantic tags for organizational/outlining and search engines, screen readers and the like. So you yourself may not see much up front for them.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the case but at least I know for me I make this mistake every now and then. Don't forget to include at the top `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Furthermore, not all browsers support HTML5 yet I believe so make sure the browser version you are using supports it (most of them should support it nowadays though).